# trying to find out if there is a command similar to "ditto"

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I know if I want to in a sense merge one directory into another without over writing everything in there using `ditto`. But now I am trying to see if there is a way I can compare both directories.

From one directory I am copying over to another directory frequently. But from the origin directory I sometimes delete stuff, which running ditto, doesn't apply to the folder I am copying/merging things over to.

So is there anything similar to ditto that can at least print out the differences between the two directories so I can remove any files I may need to remove from the directory I am copying over to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `diff` is included on OSX, but at least on Linux you can do

```
diff /path/dir1 /path/dir2
```

Comment: did, not know `diff` worked on directories.. nice..

Comment: If you add `-r`, the diff command will work recursively into any subdirectories as well.  And, if you don't care about the exact differences, `-q` will show you just the file names, and not the contents of the differing files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `rsync -avn source/ destination/` which will show you updated and missing/extra files.  If you include `rsync -av -n --delete source/ destination/`, it will also show you files in the destination which are not in the source.  The `-n` is a "dry run", meaning nothing is actually done--just verbose reporting about what would be done if the `-n` was omitted.